# Command to list files in usr which size exceed 1 Mb and right is 755 in Linux

Tags: linux

> Hi, how to list files in a folder which size exceed 1 Mb and right is 755 in Linux.

Comment: It is "directory", not "folder"

Comment: But still, in Linux, it is named "directory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -size +1000k -perm 755          # Greater than 1000k and permisison 755
```